# Calculate significance of correlation in grouped data with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pearson-correlation, significance

I have grouped data, for which I would like to test several basic inference statistics.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x=runif(50, min = 0, max = 25),y=runif(50, min = 10, max = 25), group=rep(0:1,25))

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(cor(x,y))
```

Here I can easily get the correlation, but I also need to check it's statistical significance. Unfortunately options like `cor.test` does not work in `dyplr`. Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: you can apply `cor.test` for groups as well. What do you need ? For example `df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(test = cor.test(x,y)$p.value)
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be what you want?

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarize(cor.test(x,y)[["p.value"]])
```

The thing is that `cor.test()` returns a list and not a single value, so you need to pick the element out of the list that you are interested in.